# When was the first adult film ever made?

Tags: production, first-appearance, film-industry, adult-movies

I was curious if anyone happens to maybe know when the first adult porno video was made on record? I was wondering how that might come about and what was the idea backing it versus how it is now?

Answer (score 7):

From [pagalparrot](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.pagalparrot.com/worlds-first-porn-or-adult-film/amp/)

> You will get surprised to know that the world’s first porn film was made in 1896 during the silent era of films. It was a seven-minute French film that featured a woman stripteasing in the bathroom, gets bathed, and then gets dressed again. The name of the movie was “Le Coucher de la Mariée.”

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Coucher_de_la_Mari%C3%A9e)

> The original film has been estimated to be around seven minutes long, but it had degraded to a poor condition in the French Film Archives until it was found in 1960. Only two minutes of the film have survived, which includes the undressing sequence.

But you can also say it's the known oldest porn film which partially survived.

Comment: If people are curious, the movie is on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHnL_ZJKHcU . I didn't watch it til the end (3 minutes is a long time!) but it isn't porn or even erotic in the modern standard.

Comment: I guess, to properly answer the question, we'll first need to come up with a [common definition for "porn."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)

Comment: @Steve-O Really interesting idea, and I'd like to add that what is "pornographic" has changed over the years - and decades - and in this case centuries! A good start for a definition is that the entertainment is designed to arouse the viewer, but that falls short because plenty of current R-rated movies contain highly arousing scenes and sequences even though they aren't considered pornography. Back in 1896, though, that definition ("designed to arouse the audience") _may_ have been considered pornographic ... at least in America, if not in more sexually-comfortable countries.